# Update class member gradually

Tags: python, class-design, concurrency, class

Consider the following:

```py
import typing

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_member: typing.Optional[dict] = None

    def update_member(self):
        self.my_member = {}
        self.my_member.update({"a": 1})
        self.my_member.update({"b": 2})
```

Here what I'm concerned about is the impact of gradually updating a class member. I took a dictionary for example but this can be true for any mutable object.

As a comparison, we can create a local object an only update the class member at last:

```py
import typing

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_member: typing.Optional[dict] = None

    def update_member(self):
        data = {}
        data.update({"a": 1})
        data.update({"b": 2})
        
        self.my_member = data
```

In case the code gets interrupted some how or maybe in a multi-thread environment, can the second approach be safer?